# Firebase development advice

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS Firebase app that has been in production for 3 years.
I an now ready to start work on the Android version which will access the same database.
I clearly don’t want to use my live database for development so what is the recommended way to develop the Android version?

My plan is to create a prototype database for development and when I am happy change the Firebase database reference in the new Android version to the live production one.
If there is a better way to do this it would be great to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to export the data from the live version (either from the Firebase console or through the API), and import that into a new project (again: either through the console or the API).

An alternative is to start with an empty database and just the same set of security rules, and then generate data. This is a better approach (as you won't be mucking around with user data), but it does typically require a bit more work to set up.

Comment: And then when I am happy with the Android version I just change the database reference to the live database?